# How do I bind the 'out' function to a dynamically generated element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have been stuck on this all day. I cannot seem to get jquery to register when it has left (raised the 'out' event) on a dynamically generated element.

I am trying to build a sortable list and I need the spacer in between elements to highlight when the user drags close to it and then to disappear when the user moves away from it. So far is it 60 % working but I just cannot get jQuery to trigger when the mouse moves away.

**HTML**

```
  <div id="draggable">drag me</div>      
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="tray"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#draggable{
  z-index:1001;
}

.item{
  width:400px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:red;
}

.tray{
    width:400px;

    background-color:yellow;
}

.tray.open{
  height:30px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#draggable').draggable({
  revert:true,
  stop:function(){
    $('.tray').removeClass('open');
  }
});

$('.item').droppable({
  over:function(event, ui){

    var target = $(event.target);

    target.parent()
    .find('.tray')
    .addClass('open').droppable({
      out:function(){
            alert('leaving and will close all trays');
          }
    });

  }
});
```

UPDATE : It is probably hard to understand what I want. Basically all I want is for the yellow box that appears to stay open until the user hovers 'onto' it. Then when they hover 'out' of the yellow box I want it to close immediately (which it isn't doing).

The problem is that the method for 'out' on the yellow box does not work while the user has dragged and held down on the mouse. But it starts working like normal after they let go....

I am trying to make a sortable list with sections that highlight in the middle between items.

[CSSBin](http://jsbin.com/kadige/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: If drag element _below_ yellow background , alert is called.

Comment: no it is only called sometimes. It is not reliable.

Comment: Interesting. When tried initially , `console` was open , with `console` having height reaching approximately 20 or 30px below yellow background. When `drag me` dragged down to "touch" horizontal scroll bar at "Output" window, `alert` occured each ooccasion - when `drag me` "touched" bottom of window / scroll bar. You are correct - with `console` closed , no alert called , even when `drag me` dragged down to same scroll bar at "output" window. Tried with open console , to height just below yellow background? Does `ui` source contain variables calculating draggable area ? and/or `windowHeight` ?

Comment: Its not working for first time. it alerts from second time if i comment the line in stop function. If u can describe what you are trying to achieve that will be of help

Comment: Try http://jsbin.com/batetetusiqu/1/edit . Moved `alert` to last `out` function

Comment: It needs to just do alert when it leaves the yellow not the red though, I need it to trigger on the dynamic content....